# Query Optimization for Subquery

Tags: mysql, query-performance, query

Please help to optimize below MySQL query

```
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT u.name,u.avatar,u.occupation, 
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(revenue)FROM LOGS WHERE user_id = u.id AND TYPE ='conversion') AS revenue,
        (SELECT SUM(revenue) FROM LOGS WHERE TYPE ='impression' AND user_id = u.id ) AS totalImpressions,
        (SELECT SUM(revenue) FROM LOGS WHERE user_id = u.id AND TYPE ='conversion') AS totalConversions,
        (SELECT MIN(TIME) FROM LOGS WHERE user_id = u.id ) AS minTime,
        (SELECT MAX(TIME) FROM LOGS WHERE user_id = u.id ) AS maxTime
         FROM users u  
         )q
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform your query to:

```
SELECT u.name
     , u.avatar
     , u.occupation
     , x.revenue
     , x.totalImpressions
     , ...
     , x.maxTime
FROM (
  SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN TYPE ='conversion' 
                                    THEN revenue 
                                    ELSE '' 
                               END) AS revenue
                , SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE ='impression'
                                THEN revenue 
                                ELSE 0
                           END) AS totalImpressions
                ...
                , MAX(TIME) as maxTime
  FROM LOGS
  GROUP BY user_id
) as x
JOIN users u
    ON x.user_id = u.id
```

that will access the logs table 1 time compared to your query that accesses it 5 times